# Какая видеоплатформа используется для размещения / доставки / воспроизведения видео на этой странице?

Tags: google-chrome

https://www.chelseafc.com/en/videos
нужно определить видеоплатформу
Я нашёл ссылку на ресурс cloudinary, но является ли это ввидеоплатформой, поскльку при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши написано что видео на базе JW Player